# Code Coverage not populated after sonar analysis

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube5.6

I am using sonarqube5.6.1.

I have a multi module project for which i am running sonar analysis using the below command.

```
mvn org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.1.1:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://bamboo.in.XXX.com:8085 -Dsonar.analysis.mode=publish -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=false
```

But code coverage is not getting populated at all.

Can some one help. I could see the below warnings, Not sure if that's the reason.

```
[INFO] Process project properties
[WARNING] /!\ A multi-module project can't have source folders, so '/ssdd5/sameenud/dev/trunk/AAAA/BBBB/CCCC/DDDD/src/main/java' won't be used for the analysis. If you want to analyse files of this folder, you should create another sub-module and move them inside it.
```

The folder structure we have is as below,

```
AAAA
   --BBBB
       pom.xml
       ---CCCC
          pom.xml
          ---DDDD
             pom.xml
```

I tried compiling it manual, But no luck, Same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue, 0.0% coverage & no unit tests count on Sonar dashboard with SonarQube 6.7.2:
Maven : 3.5.2,
Java : 1.8,
Jacoco : Worked with 7.0/7.9/8.0,
OS : Windows

After a lot of struggle finding for correct solution, resolved issue with this configuration my parent pom looks like:

```
 <properties>
            <!--Sonar -->
            <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
            <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
            <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>

        </properties>

        <build>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.5</source>
                            <target>1.5</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.4.0.905</version>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>0.7.9</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                            <append>true</append>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
```

I've tried few other options like *jacoco-aggregate* & even creating a sub-module by including that in parent pom but nothing really worked & this is simple. I see in logs `<sonar.jacoco.reportPath>` is deprecated,but still works as is and seems like auto replaced on execution or can be manually updated to `<sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>` or latest. Once after doing setup, in cmd start with **mvn clean install** then **mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install** & then do **mvn sonar:sonar** , this is what I've tried please let me know if some other best possible solution available.Hope this helps!! If not please post your question..

Comment: Worked for me. I only removed the  `<sonar.language>java</sonar.language>` since it is deprecated and produces unecessary warnings...

Comment: Cool, I believe that can be optional & few other tags as well seems to be deprecated but works good for now!! I can update my answer if I find something new !!

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube (and more specifically SonarJava analyzer) is not computing the coverage. You have to provide a coverage report in order for the analysis to import its results in the SonarQube UI and display coverage.

See the [documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project) for more information on how to achieve this.